# AWS: Not able to create an instance in different availability zone

Tags: amazon-web-services

My goal is to start a new AWS instance in us-west-1.

In the Create Instance form, I (initially) only had one VPC option available. This VPC has 3 subnets, all inside us-east.

I created a new VPC (using CIDR = "172.30.0.0/16" if that matters). Then when I try to use Create Subnet to add a subnet to it, the only options for Availability Zone are all us-east options.

I'm pretty sure that I need to create a VPC that is somehow associated with us-west-1, but I'm not sure how to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a region selector on the right side of the topmost menu bar. Everything works once the right region is selected. I didn't actually need to create a new VPC, there was already a default one set up.